# Assistance with Mac homebrew 'hg' command

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I recently installed homebrew on my Mac while following a guide someone made to run certain things natively that couldn't be before. I also installed and updated 'pip'. I am having problems with a command:

```
sudo pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

I get the following message in return:

```
The directory '/Users/WilsonHuijsie/Library/Caches/pip/http'
or its parent directory is not owned by the current user
and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions
and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you 
may want sudo's -H flag. The directory 
'**/Users/WilsonHuijsie/Library/Caches/pip**' or its parent
directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels 
has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of 
that directory. If executing pip with sudo, 
you may want sudo's -H flag.

Collecting hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame

Cloning hg http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame to /private/tmp/pip-req-build-6TUq7C

Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory while executing command hg clone --noupdate -q http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame /private/tmp/pip-req-build-6TUq7C Cannot find command 'hg' - do you have 'hg' installed and in your PATH?
```

I have full access rights to my computer so I don't know what the first part is about, and I assume the last part is to do with a problem with 'hg'? If anyone could help it would be very much appreciated.

Also note, while I am not experienced in terminal/homebrew commands and do not know what many mean/do, I do understand coding in general, especially python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing pygame by just doing `pip install pygame` if you are using Python2 and `pip3 install pygame` if you are using Python3. If you look at the bottom of the error, it tells you that you don't have `hg` installed. You should be able to just install directly as mentioned above.